# force update returned value in render

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using I18 to support multi-language on my app. This is my code

```
class MyClass extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
    this.state = {
    dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(data.apps),
    };
  }

 render() {
      const language = this.props.language
      alert(language);
      return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

      <Text> {I18n.t('settings.title')} </Text> // This get updated
      <ListView contentContainerStyle={styles.list}
          dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
          renderRow={(rowData) => 
      <Text> {I18n.t('settings.title')} </Text> // Not updated
      <Text> rowData.[language] </Text> // Not updated
```

The problem is that when the language is switched, the render get called and popup the new language but the returned value dose not change.

Comment: Where do you get `Text` component from? Could your share its code? Maybe the error is in there since you are propagating a prop that is changing.

Comment: are you sure that alert(language) is also not displaying the old value?

Comment: Render wont change when there is a change in props , try setting it to the component's state and then you will get what you want

Comment: Right, just saw the `react-native` tag. And how do reducer and action creator look like?

Comment: @Jeffin Render get called but the return value dose not change

Comment: @LinasMickevicius yes I am sure

Comment: it's impossible that alert(language) is displaying new value and {language} is displaying old value

Comment: @LinasMickevicius I just figure out that only the components inside a ListView dose not get updated. I didn't post the listView code to simplify the code :/